# How to create custom Spark-Native functions without forking/modifying Spark itself

Tags: apache-spark, user-defined-functions, catalyst-optimizer

I am looking into converting some UDFs/UDAFs to Spark-Native functions to leverage Catalyst and codegen.

Looking through some examples (for example:  https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/7214/files for Levenshtein) it seems like we need to add these functions to the Spark framework itself (i.e. via FunctionRegistry.scala).

Is there a way to add custom Spark-Native functions in "userspace" i.e. without forking/modifying the actual Spark codebase?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want it to be available in sql queries?

Comment: Yes that would be great.

Comment: To all reading, this, I finally found some resources on how to add Spark-native functions: [here](https://github.com/swoop-inc/spark-alchemy/wiki/Spark-Native-Functions) and [here](https://blog.simeonov.com/2018/11/14/apache-spark-native-functions/). If I manage to get it working I will post the answer.

Comment: @cozos did you ever get this to work?

Comment: @user3613290 Yes I got it to work. I followed this open source project which implements Spark Native functions and registers them: https://github.com/swoop-inc/spark-alchemy/blob/master/alchemy/src/main/scala/com/swoop/alchemy/spark/expressions/hll/HLLFunctionRegistration.scala

Comment: @cozos ah awesome. I didn't want to import third party repos, so I actually just registered some functions directly in the FunctionRegistry. Unfortunately I'm not on Spark 3.0+ where it looks like they've streamlined the process https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSessionExtensions.html#injectFunction-scala.Tuple3-

Comment: @user3613290 Yeah I actually did this before Spark 3.0, by basically overloading FunctionRegistry. The open source project I linked has a tag/release in Spark 2.X which is a good example.